# import QtQuick.Controls 2.1 QML MODULE NOT FOUND

Tags: qt, qt-creator, qml

I am using Qt Creator 2.4.1 base on Qt 4.7.4(32 bit) on windows. I have to create a table in QML using Table View. When i try import QtQuick.Controls 2.1 i get the error QML MODULE NOT FOUND. Same error on Qt Creator 2.6.2 based on Qt 5.0.1.
Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The module `QtQuick.Controls` has been added on `Qt 5.1` and is currently at the `1.0` version. It also requires you having `QtQuick` version 2.0, introduced with `Qt 5` So if you want to use `TableView` you would have to update your current `Qt` version to at least 5.1 and then use these `import` statement:

```
import QtQuick 2.0
import QtQuick.Controls 1.0
```

Also, as indicated by [Armaghast](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3221328/armaghast) in the comment, if you are moving to the latest Qt version (currently Qt 5.2.1) you should use

```
import QtQuick 2.2
import QtQuick.Controls 1.1
```

Comment: Thanks for your time.Do i have to install Qt 5.1 now. What about Qt Creator version.

Comment: You should install Qt5.1 and use the Qt Creator that is bundled with the version you downloaded. If you can it would be even better to move to the latest official Qt release, currently Qt 5.2.1

Comment: A small addition: with Qt 5.2, QtQuick.Controls' version is 1.1, and QtQuick one is 2.2, small additions and different implementations are the main change I think.

Answer (score 3):

In my case running `qmake` fixed issue.

**Update 2020 (new way):**
In some cases it not helped. Instead this solution helped greatly.
In the QtCreator, open settings/preferences and go to *QtQuick > QtQuick Designer* and select `Use QML emulation layer...` option in *Qml Emulation Layer* section and get your most newer version of Qt to it as follow:
[image: settings of qml emulatiln]

Comment: same, I clicked on the hammer (build) icon and it resolved the missing module. I have a standard Windows Qt 5.13.1 install with Qt Creator 4.10.0

Answer (score 0):

In October 2016, Qt Qtuick Controls 2.1 were released as part of Qt 5.8

If anybody (like me) stumbles upon this error when using someone else code, you need to install Qt 5.8 or newer. Lower versions will fail to run the QML GUI.

More info at: http://blog.qt.io/blog/2016/10/06/qt-quick-controls-2-1-and-beyond/