# QML import QtCharts module error

Tags: qt, import, qml

When I try to import the QtCharts module to my QML files y always get the same warning message:

> "found not working imports: file: C:/....   module "QtCharts" is not
>   installed"

I'm using OpenSource QtCreator 4.0.3 with Qt 5.7.0.

I have the folder QtCharts in the path:  `C:\Qt\5.7\mingw53_32\qml`

I've also included the folder path using the property in the .pro file:

```
QML2_IMPORT_PATH: C:\Qt\5.7\mingw53_32\qml
```

What am I missing?

Here is a simple test code:

// QtChartsTest.pro

```
TEMPLATE = app

QT += qml quick
QT += charts

CONFIG += c++11

SOURCES += main.cpp

RESOURCES += qml.qrc

# Additional import path used to resolve QML modules in Qt Creator's code model

QML2_IMPORT_PATH = C:\Qt\5.7\mingw53_32\qml


# Default rules for deployment.
include(deployment.pri)
```

// Main.cpp

```
#include <QGuiApplication>
#include <QQmlApplicationEngine>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QGuiApplication app(argc, argv);

    QQmlApplicationEngine engine;
    engine.load(QUrl(QStringLiteral("qrc:/main.qml")));

    return app.exec();
}
```

// Main.qml

```
import QtQuick 2.7
import QtQuick.Window 2.2
import QtCharts 2.1

Window {
    visible: true
    width: 640
    height: 480
    title: qsTr("Hello World")

    Text {
        text: qsTr("Hello World")
        anchors.centerIn: parent
    }
}
```

Comment: Please show the import line from the code. Btw, it should work w/o setting the import path.

Comment: I just ran into the same problem and am running the same version of Qt as yourself.  Did you solve it?  If so, it would be helpful to know how.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [import QtQuick.Controls 2.1 QML MODULE NOT FOUND](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22320541/import-qtquick-controls-2-1-qml-module-not-found)

Answer (score 0):

I was stuck on a similar issue and was frustrated by Qt's documentation on the subject, so I'll put my method of solving my own issues here for posterity.

I'm not sure of the exact cause of your issue, but I can offer you a suggestion to try and troubleshoot it.

In your main.cpp add the following line.
`qDebug()<<engine.importPathList();`

So your main will be

```
#include <QGuiApplication>
#include <QQmlApplicationEngine>
#include <QDebug>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QGuiApplication app(argc, argv);
    QQmlApplicationEngine engine;
    qDebug()<<engine.importPathList();
    engine.load(QUrl(QStringLiteral("qrc:/main.qml")));

    return app.exec();
}
```

This will include the complete list of include paths.  If you do not see the include path listed there you can add it by adding the following line:

`engine.addImportPath(directory);`

where "directory" is a QString to the include directory.

My understanding is that the `QML2_IMPORT_PATH` variable only applies at run time, and not at compile time, which means that QtCreator does not see the path when it compiles. `engine.addImportPath(directory);` on the other hand adds the path prior to starting the qml engine, (and thus the first qml import statements)

I am not saying this is the best way to solve your issue, but it did help me solve my issue.

Answer (score 0):

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    // Qt Charts uses Qt Graphics View Framework for drawing, therefore QApplication must be used.
    QApplication app(argc, argv);

    QQuickView viewer;

    // The following are needed to make examples run without having to install the module
    // in desktop environments.
#ifdef Q_OS_WIN
    QString extraImportPath(QStringLiteral("%1/../../../../%2"));
#else
    QString extraImportPath(QStringLiteral("%1/../../../%2"));
#endif
    viewer.engine()->addImportPath(extraImportPath.arg(QGuiApplication::applicationDirPath(),
                                      QString::fromLatin1("qml")));
    //***** [Solve] FORCE THE MODULE TO BE IMPORTED.
    QObject::connect(viewer.engine(), &QQmlEngine::quit, &viewer, &QWindow::close);
    
    qDebug() << viewer.engine()->importPathList();

    viewer.setTitle(QStringLiteral("QML Axes"));
    viewer.setSource(QUrl("qrc:/qml/qmlaxes/main.qml"));
    viewer.setResizeMode(QQuickView::SizeRootObjectToView);
    viewer.show();

    return app.exec();
}
```

[Output through qDebug()]
("/home/snjee/workspace_qt/maxelecPrjs/build-maxCoffeeTdsMeterApp-Desktop_Qt_5_15_2_GCC_64bit-Debug", "qrc:/qt-project.org/imports", "/opt/Qt/5.15.2/gcc_64/qml")

You can find the answer in the built-in "QML Axes" example source.